# Neo4j - What's the best way to check if multiple items are in the DB based on a set of ids

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a bunch of 1000 ids (like: "id1", "id2", "id3" ... "id100") of "items" that I get from 3rd party server. I have a user who owns already owns 10-50 "items" like below:

```
(user)-[:owns]->(:ITEM{id: "id1"})
```

Those 100 item ids from 3rd party server are random. I need to write a cypher query that tells how many of those 3rd party item a given user already owns.

Currently I am doing:

```
MATCH (user{id:userId}-[:OWNS]->(i:ITEM) 
WHERE i.id = "id1" || i.id = "id2" || i.id = "id3" ..... || i.id = i"d100"
RETURN i
```

Is there a better approach?

Please Note: The number of items owned by user might be in the 1000s, where as number of item ids from 3rd party is always constant (100). For a given user, all 100 items might be a match or 0 or 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ideally you'd just pass the collection of IDs in as a parameter:

```
MATCH (user {id:userId})-[:OWNS]->(i:ITEM)
WHERE i.id IN {ids}
RETURN COUNT(i) AS items
```

But you can also declare it within the query:

```
MATCH (user {id:userId})-[:OWNS]->(i:ITEM)
WHERE i.id IN ['id1', 'id2', 'id3', ..., 'id100']
RETURN COUNT(i) AS items
```

Comment: very simpler query, thanks. I would however split the user match and the (user)-[:OWNS]->(item) iot avoid the traversal matcher operation and benefit of the user/id index.

Comment: Thanks Nicole. 2nd version is simpler for me. Not sure how to deal w/ 1st version from node.js (i.e. pass IDs as 'parameter' for {ids})

Answer (score 2):

You can use the FILTER function against a path in Cypher :

```
WITH ["id1","id2","id3","id4"] as ids
MATCH (user:User {id: userId})
WITH  filter(x in ids WHERE (user)-[:OWNS]->(:Item {id: x}) ) as itemMatches
RETURN size(itemMatches)
```

In this example, if the user owns items with ids 1, 3 and 4 it will return you 3.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know we could use "With" as a starting word in cypher.